# Input multiple csv file and get one output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have 30 csv files. I want to give it as input in for loop, in pandas?

Each file has names such as fileaa, fileab,fileac,filead,....

And i would like to receive one output.

Usually i use read_csv but due to memory error, 'read_csv' doesn't work.

```
f = "./file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="/", header=0, dtype=str)
```

P.S only the first file has the column title but number of columns are same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931068/pandas-read-csv-memoryerror, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Details please: how many columns does each file have? how do you want the output formatted (perhaps with a small example)? what is the backtrace for the error you get? is `file.csv` one of the thirty files?

Comment: @Vinay exactly ! thank you ! i am trying the same code to see if it works ! i will let you know if "low_memory=True" flag works

Comment: @Nick each file has around 50 rows and numerous lines (5gb data)

Comment: @Vinay doesnt work! :( memory error

Comment: try blaze: http://blaze.pydata.org ... Sounds like you either need to get a beefier machine (pandas is in-memory only), use something like blaze, or move straight to spark (which you can run locally if you want) and process it in smaller pieces. for blaze, you will probably need to recode the csv files into a database (sqlite comes built-in) or hdf5 (which pandas can handle directly).

Comment: You mean 50 columns? If each file is 5GB, then you'll need more than 150GB of memory to hold them all. If you don't have that much memory, then the only thing you can do is process them in small enough pieces (say 1000 rows at a time or 1000000 rows at a time: whatever your machine can do) to fit in memory and use the file system to hold intermediate results, then concatenate the results into a single file. Why do you want them in a single file? That's going to give you even more trouble in the future.

Comment: exactly !! thats my question ! so i have split this one huge file into 30 small files ! now i want to load them in loop and get the result in one single file

Comment: @WaltReed Yes ! lot of operations !

Comment: @walt reed nop!

Comment: This will allow you to read the csv file in chunks. Try playing around with the parameter. Maybe `chunksize=500000`, and if that's too much, bump it down.

Comment: okay! thanks ! i will try that :)